# How to configure WCF endpoints for use in rdp client session so they can use a central service?

Tags: c#, wcf

Im working through some WCF examples. Presently there is a order entry application with a sales register. In order for users to get latest transactions they have to manually refresh the register to pull from DB.

Im going to implement an event model via WCF and Publisher-Subscriber Framework such that any users order entry, signals all other instances of the app to refresh their transaction register if that screen is open.

So the examples so far are all using configurations like below:

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
         <service name="TrafficLightSubscriptionService">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8001/TrafficLightSubscriptionService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ITrafficLightSubscription"/>   
         </service>
         <service name="TrafficLightEventService">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8002/TrafficLightEventService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ITrafficLightEvents"/>
         </service>
      </services>
   </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

This works fine for learning etc on a single machine with IIS but I will need to implement on a small Windows Server 2003 domain (1 server, 4-5 clients) where "some" the clients are connecting remotely via rdp sessions and other via LAN.

I would prefer to host the service as a Windows Service not in IIS. So pls point me in the direction of how to configure bindings for this scenario.

1. Is it as simple as just swapping out http://l.o.ca.l.h.o.s.t for an IP number.
2. If so what to do if IPs are dynamically allocated?
3. Are there any security considerations re: access? How can I allow any authenticated user to connect to the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversing the RDP boundary is not trivial. If you look closely when creating remote connections, you have options of what local resources you want to share - audio, printers, file system... they don't share IP, nor you can get to client IP from inside a targeted rdp host.
But, I'm not sure you actually need this - the clients that connect via RDP sessions - is their app client on their local computer, or are the just opening their clients after they connect, inside a rdp desktop? If the client is on their 'home' pc, than you have a problem, otherwise, it doesn't make any difference how they connect, as long as the clients are on the same network.

As for the other part of the question - I'd advise strongly against self hosting an WCF, because IIS offers reliability which could be hard to immitate if you host it yourself.
Secondly - if you need IIS on each of the clients, then something's probably wrong with your software architecture. I would guess that only Server needs an IIS, and servers by default have static IP (if they don't, than refer to them by their domain computer name, and your DNS will do the routing). The clients should provide their current IP whenever they subscribe.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes it sure does thanks. Yes users use the app from within their Windows Session and only server has IIS.